# How to output results in a Jframe

Tags: java, jframe, output

I am currently working on an SJF scheduling program that will output data using GUI. But i am having trouble outputing data to Jframe panel. Help will be appreciated. I want the output of the below mentioned code be displayed on a Jframe.

```
 public static void WTs() {
    int totalWT=0;

  for(int x=1;x<=n;x++)
  {
      WT[x]=BT[x-1]+WT[x-1];
      System.out.print("\nWaiting time for Process" + JB[x] + ":\t" + WT[x]
      + " units \t");
      totalWT= totalWT+ WT[x];
  }
        //////////////////////////2nd output/////////////////////////////
 public static void Display()
      { 

     for(int x=0;x<n;x++)
    {
      System.out.println(" JOB \t" +JB[x]);
      System.out.println(" BURST TIME\t"+BT[x]);

    }
```

GUI CODE

```
    package javaapplication22;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;
    import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
public class NewClass extends JFrame {
private final JTextArea item1;
public NewClass(){super("SJF PROJECT ");
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
item1=new JTextArea(" ");
    add(item1);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);

  }
  }
```

GUI CODE IN MAIN CLASS

```
NewClass k= new NewClass();
 k.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 k.setSize(275, 180);
 k.setVisible(true);
 k.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 

  try {
 Thread.sleep(1000);  
  k.hide();//1000 milliseconds is one second.
  } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  }
```

Comment: where is code for GUI that has JFrame

Comment: More people are likely to try to analyze your code if you indent it properly and consistently.  Currently, it’s pretty much all over the place.

Comment: @VGR           Yeah man sorry i need to work on that

Answer (score 0):

Following things you need to do:

1. Add a method to your `NewClass` which will provide access to JTextArea item1.
2. In your `Display` method you need to create a String instead of writing to `System.out`. Use `StringBuilder` to create the string to be displayed.
3. You need to set the value of JTextArea to string created in point 2 with the help of method added in point 1

Point to remember is you will be putting text in JTextArea from a Non GUI code, so use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` for scheduling the final display on EDT.

Hope this helps